# how to print star triangle in prolog using recursion

Tags: prolog

**Anyone knows how to draw this triangle using recursive in prolog?**

```
            *
           **
          ***
         ****
        *****
       ******
```

Comment: (meta: the random highlighting of the plain ASCII stars is hilarious, and sad at the same time. @JoelSpolsky)

Comment: @WillNess That's what multi-million dollar hacks are made of which then get blamed on "well-financed state level actors" by "sources familiar with the matter".

Comment: @DavidTonhofer pastebin.com e.g. has perfectly fine Prolog highlighting, but apparently it does it server-side which apparently SE just can't afford doing...

Comment: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277514/how-to-draw-right-triangle-using-recursion-in-prolog) it is asking for the same.

Comment: Question solved. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277514/how-to-draw-right-triangle-using-recursion-in-prolog] @Elbert Jn